# Modifying a dictionary with datetime as keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example:

```
{datetime.date(2000, 1, 15): [1],
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 14): [5],
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 3): [4],
 datetime.date(2005, 1, 10): [2],
 datetime.date(2005, 1, 16): [4],
 datetime.date(2005, 1, 5): [2]}
```

to just:

```
{(2000, 1): [10], (2005,1): [8]}
```

basically omitting the day, and adding the values. I can't seem to figure out how to remove `datetime.date`.

Comment: Why are your values in an array? E.g. `[2]` instead of `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"one-line"r:

```
newdict = {
    (key.year, key.month): sum(
        v[0] for k, v in olddict.iteritems()
        if (key.year, key.month) == (k.year, k.month)
    )
    for key in olddict
}
```

```
>>> newdict
{(2000, 1): 10, (2005, 1): 8}
```

This might be a little less efficient than 0605002's answer.

---

Or a more conventional solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

newdict = defaultdict(lambda: [0])
for key in olddict:
    newdict[(key.year, key.month)][0] += olddict[key][0]
```

Comment: Does `newdict = defaultdict(lambda: [0])` mean that `[0]` will be the default value against any (even non-existent) key in `newdict`?

Comment: Ah, python keeps me amusing and this amusement never ends :)

Comment: Since your first solution uses a dictionary comprehension, the result could be immediate assigned back to `olddict` virtually making it an in-place operation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
for key in olddict:
    if (key.year, key.month) in newdict:
        newdict[(key.year, key.month)][0] += olddict[key][0]
    else:
        newdict[(key.year, key.month)] = [olddict[key][0]]
```

Learn more about `datetime` objects from [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

Comment: You should prefer `(key.year, key.month) in newdict` over  `newdict.has_key((key.year, key.month))`

Comment: `defaultdict(lambda: [0])` might be useful here

Comment: Actually I know very little about `defaultdict`, I always use the basic tools python provides.